# keycloak user session limiter does not work

Tags: keycloak

It has been over a month that I am trying to set user session limit for 1 session on keycloak 17. I’ve tried every combination I have found on internet, be it from forum or official documentation, still it does not work. What can be the cause? Thank You

I've tried every example that I could find on internet.

Comment: Can you provide more info what you did? Did you created the new browser authentication flow with session limit counter step and set it as default?

Comment: For reference https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10077#issuecomment-1283524621